# Where to find Amazon Linux 2017.03 base ami?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

There are multiple AMIs for Amazon Linux 2017.03, some of which are released within a span of mere 4 days. Where can I find information regarding what was changed between these versions?

Comment: this page has information regarding all the versions of amazon linux is it helpful https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/

Answer (score 0):

You can find such information on the Amazon Linux's release notes site: https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/
and for your particular version:
https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2017.03-release-notes/

Cheers!